# Is it possible in C# to discover all available dataTemplates via reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, datatemplate

I'd like to discover all `DataTemplate`s (defined in possibly several XAML files) contained in an assembly via reflection (or some other method that allows adding `DataTemplate`s (even to new XAML files) without having to adjust the code to discover them).

I tried something like this:

```
var allTypes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes();
var allDataTemplates = allTypes.Where(t => typeof(System.Windows.DataTemplate).IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToArray();
```

But this didn't yield any results.
I suppose that it's because `DataTemplate`s are not stored as distinct types.

What I *don't* want is to add all `DataTemplate`s from each resource dictionary manually.

Comment: Did you make sure that your `App` has started? (i.e. had it's `Run` method called)

Comment: @MisterMetaphor I call the code from the constructor of my MainWindow.